# How do I programmatically change a cell value for a programmatically inserted row in Tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

I have figured out how to programmatically copy and insert a new row in my `Tabulator` table utilizing a right-click and the `rowContextMenu` property; however I am having difficulty programmatically modifying data within the cells of the newly inserted row.

An abbreviated version of my `Tabulator` table setup code is as follows:

```
function TabulatorTimeSheet(divId) {
    try {
        var myActionContextMenu = [
            {
                label: "Copy & Paste Row",
                action: function (e, row) {
                    var myTable = row.getTable();
                    var rowData = row.getData();
                    var idx = 0;
                    myTable.addData(rowData, false)
                        .then(function (newRows) {
                            //NOTE: The [Added] column of the new row needs to be set to "true".
                            newRows.forEach(newRow => {
                                idx = newRow.getPosition(true);
                                myTable.updateRow(idx, { Added: "true" });
                            });
                            myTable.redraw(true);
                        })
                }
            }
        ]
        var table = new Tabulator(divId, {
            height: "100%",
            data: [],
            layout: "fitDataFill",
            selectable: 1,
            cellEdited: function (cell) {
                    var myTable = cell.getTable();
                    var row = cell.getRow();
                    var rowData = row.getData();
                    rowData["Changed"] = "true";
            },
            rowContextMenu: myActionContextMenu,
            columns: [
                { title: "Date Worked", field: "DateComp", responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", sorter: "date", editor: dateEditor },
                { title: "Start Time", field: "TimeStart", responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", sorter: "time", editor: timeEditor },
                { title: "Finish Time", field: "TimeFinish", responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", sorter: "time", editor: timeEditor },
                { title: "Added", field: "Added", visible: true, responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center" },
                { title: "Changed", field: "Changed", visible: false, responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center" }            ]
        });
        table.setData(myEndPointURL, { caseSelector: myCaseSelector, emplId: myEmployeeId });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

The `addData()` function inserts a copy of the selected row, as expected; however, I am unable to modify the `Added` cell of the newly inserted row.  Regardless of my efforts, I still see a blank cell.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your setup looks fine.  Instead of doing `myTable.updateRow`, use `newRows.update({field: 'new val'})`.  Because you already have the row reference, you don't need to get the id.  I think that will solve your issue.

A few other things.

1. You are only inserting one row, so instead of `myTable.addData`, use `myTable.addRow`.  Then, the return value will only be 1 row, so you don't need the `forEach`.
2. The `table.redraw` probably isn't necessary.

Here is a very simple example that should do all that you need it to.  I omitted the context menu as it isn't relevant to the issue, but you just need to move the function into there and it should be good.

https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/65cngder/6/

Comment: You are amazing!  Your solution worked perfectly.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Is there any way I can compensate you for your time?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Nope, answering questions helps me as much as it does you sometimes. It helps me keep up to date with functionality and how different parts of the library can be used.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate your help.  I plan to make a donation to Oli via his web site as soon as my current project is complete.  Like yourself, I would like to become well-versed enough with Tabulator to, perhaps, assist with answering questions at some point.